# get the name of the method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, monitoring, trace

Is there any way to get the name of the method that currently we are in it?

```
private void myMethod()
{
    string methodName = __CurrentMethodName__;
    MessageBox(methodName);
}
```

Like this.ToString() that returns the class name is there any possible way to get name of the method by something like monitoring or tracing the app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will get you name -

```
string methodName = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

OR

```
string methodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

Answer (score 6):

.NET 4.5 adds [Caller Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) attributes so you can use the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx):

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

void myMethod()
{
    ShowMethodName();
}

void ShowMethodName([CallerMemberName]string methodName = "")
{
    MessageBox(methodName);
}
```

This has the benefit of baking in the method name at compile time, rather than run time. Unfortunately there's no way to prevent someone calling `ShowMethodName("Not a real Method")`, but that may not be necessary.

Comment: The method name argument needs to be defaulted

Comment: Umm... I take it you didn't compile this. So while we're fixing, it also needs to be typed. :)

Answer (score 4):

Simply

```
public string MyMethod()
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace ();
    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame (1);

    string methodName = sf.GetMethod().Name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the info about method like this

```
var method = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
var name = method.Name;  //get method name
var parameters = method.GetParameters();  //get method parameters
```